# Remove object once clicked c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, object, mouseevent

I have objects that a user can click, once clicked there presented with a messagebox, once the messagebox after this would like the object to be removed to.

Is there a simple way of doing this ?

**My code**

```
private void redballoon_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string red_balloon_question = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Prompt("Question 5X2");

    if (red_balloon_question == "10")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Well done that is correct, you gain 1 point", "Correct Answer", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        PopBalloonCount++;             
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect, you loose 1 point", "Wrong Answer", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        PopBalloonCount--;
    }

    score.Content = "Your Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(PopBalloonCount);
    this.lastBalloonClickColor = "red_balloon"; // register the last click
}
```

**XMAL Code**

```
MouseLeftButtonDown="redballoon_click"
```

so once the message box is gone I would like the red_balloon to be removed, dose anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What type of your baloon object exactly?

Comment: then Why don't you add `WPF` tag ?

Comment: Since `Image` class in WPF does not provide `Click` event, is `redballoon_click` `MouseDown` event?

Comment: Also, you need remove object completely or just hide it?

Comment: Sorry should of provided that information its a MouseDown even, `MouseLeftButtonDown="redballoon_click"`

Comment: @hmnzr hiding it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shuld try this code:

```
private void redballoon_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //react only when baloon is clicked by left mouse button
    if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        return;

    string red_balloon_question = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Prompt("Question 5X2");

    if (red_balloon_question == "10")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Well done that is correct, you gain 1 point", "Correct Answer", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        PopBalloonCount++;             
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect, you loose 1 point", "Wrong Answer", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        PopBalloonCount--;
    }

    score.Content = "Your Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(PopBalloonCount);
    this.lastBalloonClickColor = "red_balloon"; // register the last click

    //hide baloon
    redballoon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    //or
    redballoon.Opacity = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Just need to add a few references and will let you know, thank you. Im using silverlight that is not supportive, but am trying to work around it atm

Comment: you can also use opacity trick, should work for silverlight too (added in answer).

Comment: thank you, got a few reference problems am working through at moment, as soon as i get it working ill accept answer.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Visual Studio does not recognize `Image` control?

Comment: Error  `'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'LeftButton' and no extension method 'LeftButton' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`